# API returns data, but in an undefined object. What's going on?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, asynchronous

I am using `https` and `async` to make two calls at the same time. In return I get two objects, which then I put into an array. This is how I'm making the call:

```
if (req.user.isPremium == false) {
  // Free user - Single report
  let website = req.body.website0;
  let builtWithCall = `https://api.builtwith.com/free1/api.json?KEY=key&LOOKUP=${website}`;
  let pagespeedCall = `https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v4/runPagespeed?url=https://${website}&strategy=mobile&key=key`;
  // curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v4/runPagespeed?url=https://georgiancollege.ca&strategy=mobile&key=AIzaSyDqOAEXV6WrNioBeOA76GOWzDSX2FvS--0'
  var calls = [];
  calls.push(function(callback) {
    // first call
    var results;
    https.get(builtWithCall, function(resource) {
      resource.setEncoding('utf8');
      resource.on('data', function(data) {
        results += data;
        // console.log(data);
      });
      resource.on('end', function() {
        callback(null, results);
      });
      resource.on('error', function(err) {
        callback(err);
      });
    });
  });
  calls.push(function(callback) {
    // second call
    var results;
    https.get(pagespeedCall, function(resource) {
      resource.setEncoding('utf8');
      resource.on('data', function(data) {
        results += data;
      });
      resource.on('end', function() {
        // var j = JSON.parse(results);
        // console.log(j.kind);
        callback(null, results);
      });
      resource.on('error', function(err) {
        callback(err);
      });
    });
  });
} else {
  // Premium user - comparison report
  let websites = [];
}
async.parallel(calls, function(err, results) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  // console.log('async callback ', results);
  res.render('reports/report', {
    title: 'Report',
    data: results.filter(x => x != null),
    user: req.user,
  });
});
```

The website variable comes from the view.

Now. When I just print it out in the view I get this:
[image]

And it's all cool, but I need to get the properties, to generate a user friendly report. I tried `parsing` it to JSON, but it just throws the 'unexpected value `undefined` an 0'... Which means that the async call returns it as undefined.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you seem to be doing something strange: you define a `results` var, which is `undefined`, and then you do `results += data`. This causes `results` to be `undefined {<whichever-data-is>}`. That's why you've got that 'undefined' in the page. Do not use `+=`, just use `=`, or initialise `results`: `var results = ''`;

I don't exactly get what you're tying to do by assigning, or appending `data` to another variable instead of just returning it, though, as results only gets assigned once in the function it is defined.

Comment: I couldn't think of any way to return it. Can you throw a quick example?

Comment: Just `callback(null, data)` instead of `callback(null, results)`?

Comment: I'll look into it. Thanks!